# Android creating geofence

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am working on geofence api launched in Google I/O 2013. [Creating and Monitoring Geofences](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

There is a method in the example given in the above link as follows:

```
 public void createGeofences() {
    ........
    mGeofenceList.add(mUIGeofence1.toGeofence());
    mGeofenceList.add(mUIGeofence2.toGeofence());
}
```

This method is inside onActivityResult of my activity and in the same activity i have button to save geofence and to call mLocationClient.connect() -> it's same as addGeofences() method of the example.

```
@Override
private void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
    ...
    switch (mRequestType) {
        case ADD :
            // Get the PendingIntent for the request
            mTransitionPendingIntent =
                    getTransitionPendingIntent();
            // Send a request to add the current geofences
            mLocationClient.addGeofences(
                    mGeofenceList, pendingIntent, this);
        ...
    }
}
```

In this method mGeofenceList is empty which should not be since it has been updated in onActivityResult method before.

**Problem:** the variable mGeofenceList is updated in onActivityResult but when accessed in onConnected method it is empty. Where am I wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you understand when/whether `onActivityResult` is called?
`onActivityResult` is called only as result of a previous call of `startActivityForResult`, which you are not mentioning.

Although, in this very case, the usage of this method is a bit more clever.
To quote the tutorial you provided:

> If you encounter an error, call GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog() to retrieve localized dialog that prompts users to take the correct action, then display the dialog in a DialogFragment. The dialog may allow the user to correct the problem, in which case Google Play services may send a result back to your activity. To handle this result, override the method onActivityResult().

So, if you are using the code from the tutorial, the `onActivityResult` is only called when:

1. There is something wrong with Google Play Services
2. You prompted the user with dialog returned by `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()` to fix the error
3. User successfully changed settings/etc. using another activity
4. The activity returned with some resultCode

Since you are most probably running Google Play Services without any problems, the `onActivityResult` is never called, and therefore your list is always empty.

I suggest moving your `createGeofences()` to `onCreate` (if you are just testing and you do not have a lot of them) or to some background thread (if you have them a lot or you no not want to slow down the activity start)

Comment: My first activity(A) is calling activity B which contains a map. On choosing a location, user is taken back to A and that's where onActivityResult is called and data is indeed received (I have checked on Log). But the variables (mGeofenceList) does not contain the updated value when retrieved in onConnected(Bundle dataBundle).
For now, I have saved the data returne in onActivityResult in SharedPreferences and retrieve it when needed in onConnected, but still can't find the missing concept here. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Oh, well, that explains a lot :D Just in case: Are you really sure you are referencing your global list correctly? Once it took me ages looking for similar bug only to find out I used local: ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList(); instead of global: myList = new ArrayList(); I know it is silly, but, still, happens sometimes.

Comment: Yes it is global. It has been instantiated in onCreateView of fragment